# Javascript regex oddity in Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I freely admit that my comprehension of regular expressions is spotty. That said, I can't make head or tail of this. This only happens in Chrome.

I have this bit of code to pull out the text between `body` tags in an HTML string:

```
var extractBodyHtml = function (obj) {
    var regex = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>/g;
    //if (obj.match(regex)) {
    if (regex.test(obj)) {
        return RegExp.$1;
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
};
```

**Update**

I cannot reproduce this in a fiddle. In fact the exact same code works in one place, against the same HTML, but not another. Lest you think I am crazy here's the debugger.

[image]
<sub>(source: [outsharked.com](http://www.outsharked.com/chromedebug.png))</sub>

Note the commented line. That was the first version. It worked, sometimes. In other situations, `RegExp.$1` would return just a single character, "r". This is always reproducible for a particular situation.

Note that `obj.match(regex)` always returns the correct match (including the body tags) but accessing the backreference would give the "r" *sometimes*.

When I changed the code to `regex.test(obj)` things always work correctly, and `RegExp.$1` returns the inner content.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? What is wrong with `document.body.innerHTML`?

Comment: Because it's a string. It's not part of the DOM. It's a response from a ajax query.

Comment: Can you post an example of your code not working in jsfiddle?

Comment: I have not (so far) been able to repro in in a fiddle. I can't query the same data source b/c of cross-site restrictions, and it doesn't happen with simple test strings. Still trying...

Comment: OK - I went so far as to copy/format the entire thing as a string and it doesn't repro the problem. On the original, it is in an iFrame, so perhaps this has something to do with it.

Comment: Scratch that it's not an iFrame in the original (mixed up two different places that form is uesed)

Answer (score 1):

You should (almost) never use a regular expression to parse html.

Whatever response you get from your AJAX requests, you can pass it to jQuery's constructor (if it's valid html). You can then parse it with jQuery's regular methods:

```
$.get('path/to/html', function(data){
    // "data" will hold your entire html returned
    var theHTML = $(data).find('body').html(); // this'll have what you're looking for
});
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly why I am doing this. That doesn't always work because jQuery parses HTML by adding it to the DOM, and if its wrapped in HTML already it chokes. `$(data)` for a full HTML document returns nothing.

Comment: @jamietre: Did you test it? It works for me. Your HTML might have errors in it. Try running it through the W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org/ . And FYI, jQuery does not `parse HTML by adding it to the DOM`. It creates a document fragment in memory, and parses that.

Comment: What I mean is, it uses the browser to parse it. It doesn't have its own HTML parser.

Comment: OK - but that's what I mean by "doesn't always work." Now try this: http://jsfiddle.net/e4jaC/6/

Comment: @jamietre: It seems that when passing a full `html` fragment, you get a collection containing the `head` part separate, and the `body` part separate. So, all you have to do is `$(data).eq(1)`, which'll get you the `body` part.

Comment: look at the last fiddle update. That's great if you can depend on it being in the 2nd element, but you can't, since whitespace will change that.

Comment: @jamietre: You can always test your nodes to ascertain that they're not empty: http://jsfiddle.net/e4jaC/7/

Comment: Okay - this is another way to handle it, but its more code than what I was trying to do in the first place! But I'm still wondering why the regex doesn't work.

Comment: ... and more importantly why it works with "test" and not with "match" which should have identical effects on the RegExp object

Comment: @jamietre let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2896/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-jamietre)